# Is using a label enough or should I add aria attributes?

Tags: html, forms, accessibility, wai-aria

**Preamble**
A colleague told me that, to make our web apps more accessible, everything needed some aria-* attribute. I've been reading through articles regarding accessibility *on w3.org, angular.io, mdn web docs and here on stackoverflow*, and have come to the conclusion that he definitely got that wrong. But I still couldn't get a clear overview on which elements really need or should have an aria-* attribute to make them more accessible and which don't. If you've got resources on that, please share.

**Question**
Let's say I have a form with input fields with labels. Basic, like so:

```
<!-- v1: -->
  <label for="input-favAnimal">Favourite animal:</label>
  <input type="text" id="input-favAnimal" placeholder="e.g. Penguin"/>
```

Is that already assistive technology friendly or should I add aria-labelledby (or anything else) to the input to improve accessibility? Aforementioned colleague suggested this:

```
<!-- v2: -->
  <label for="input-favAnimal" id="label-favAnimal">Favourite animal:</label>
  <input type="text" id="input-favAnimal" placeholder="e.g. Penguin" aria-labelledby="label-favAnimal" />
```

v2 frankly just looks doubled to me. But again, my only knowledge regarding accessibility is based on having read some articles.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `A colleague told me that, to make our web apps more accessible, everything needed some aria-* attribute.` Anything built by a developer with this attitude is almost guaranteed imo to be horribly inaccessible - and almost certainly less so than the same website with no aria attributes at all.

Comment: To back up @RobinZigmond's comment, see WebAIM's "million" report.  It says that sites that use ARIA incorrectly have **more** accessibility issues than sites that **don't** use ARIA.  https://webaim.org/projects/million/#aria.  Please don't let your colleague do any ARIA coding :-) and send them to some accessibility training.

Comment: @RobinZigmond okay good, glad I understood that correctly, thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Label alone is fine as long as you have the `for` and `id` attributes matching, like you do in your v1 example. You can see this is the recommended solution wherever it's possible to do so in the [related section in the W3C WAI documentation](https://www.w3.org/WAI/tutorials/forms/labels/#associating-labels-explicitly).

Why? A label is great because it is helpful for vision impaired users and users with motor control issues (and all users, for that matter!) can click on the label to focus the input. Aria labels are beneficial for vision impaired users because screen readers will be able to indicate to the user which elements relate to one another. But if a label is already there and is properly set up as you have it with `for` and `id` attributes, it doesn't do anything extra.

There is a lot of information that you can use for future work in [the W3C WAI documentation](https://www.w3.org/WAI/design-develop/) as well as these [Aria Design Patterns](https://w3c.github.io/aria-practices/examples/). (And many more places too!)

Comment: **But** if you have an error message or *additional* help text for the input, you should associate it with your input by means of `aria-describedby`.

Answer (score 1):

It's perfectly useless to add aria-label or aria-labelledby in this situation, as the input field is already perfectly linked with its label.

ARia-label and aria-labelledby are ment for situations where you can't do anything else. One of the most important rules of ARIA is to don't use it, unless you really need it.

Comment: To back up @quentinc's answer regarding the first rule of ARIA is to not use ARIA, here's the official W3C spec that says that - https://www.w3.org/TR/aria-in-html/#rule1.  It basically says use native html as much as possible (such as `<label for="ID">`), which you are doing.